# Read annotation value from interface?

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

I am developing a framework which allows developers to do database operations through service layer. Service classes will send the database request dto object which will be annotated with sql ID to use as ID in MyBatis. Later I will read the annotation value by reflection.

First of all, I created a custom annotation interface.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface MyBatisMapper {
    String namespace() default "";
    String sqlId() default "";
}
```

And interface for database request dto object.

```
public interface IReqDto {    
    public String getDaoType();
}
```

And database request dto object which will implement the above IReqDto interface.

```
@MyBatisMapper(namespace="User", sqlId="userInsert")
public class UserInsertReqDto implements IReqDto{
    //beans and getters/setters
}
```

The above bean may vary as requirement of the developer. This is not part of the framework. Developer must implement `IReqDto` interface in any kind of database request object he use.

What I am trying is to read the annotated values (`namespace and sqlId`) from database invoker class by using reflection.

I understand that I can get the annotated value by doing this.

```
Class<UserInsertReqDto> ReqDto = UserInsertReqDto.class;        
for(Annotation annotation : ReqDto.getAnnotations()) {
    System.out.println(annotation.toString());
}
```

But my problem is, as the `UserInsertReqDto` will vary, I tried to use reflection to `IReqDto` interface.

```
Class<IReqDto> ReqDto = IReqDto.class;
```

Well, surely it doesn't work. 
The question is - how can I read the annotated value from database request object in this situation? Thanks.

Comment: You can only get the annotation if an annotation exists. `UserInsertReqDto` is annotated, `IReqDto` is not. It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Sorry for uncleared question. `UserInsertReqDto` is just example. This will only exist when user of the framework create it. I have to prepare in the framework to get annotation of whatever `ReqDto` class which implement `IReqDto`. Thank you for your time sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm still misunderstanding your question, so correct me if necessary.

You will be given an object of a custom implementation of `ReqDto`

```
ReqDto object = ...; // get instance
Class<?> clazz = object.getClass(); get actual type of the instance

for(Annotation annotation : clazz.getAnnotations()) { // these are class annotations
    System.out.println(annotation.toString());
}
```

or

```
MyBatisMapper mapperAnnotation = clazz.getAnnotation(MyBatisMapper.class);
if (mapperAnnotation != null) {
    System.out.println(mapperAnnotation.namespace()
    System.out.println(mapperAnnotation.sqlId()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Reflection works regardless of the type. So, instead of referring to the concrete class, simply use `Object#getClass()` and/or `Class<?>`. E.g.

```
public Metadata getMetadata(Object pojo) {
   Annotation annotation = pojo.getAnnotation(MyBatisMapper.class);
   if (annotation == null) {
      return null;
   }
   return new Metadata(annotation.getNamespcae(), annotation.getSqlId());
}
```

where `Metadata` is just a value class that you can use later on that contains the values about the object. You can also directly work with the `MyBatisWrapper` annotation.

Comment: Just fix the declared type of your `annotation` variable. And `pojo.getClass().getAnnotation..`